# How to retrieve hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto value from Hibernate at runtime?

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration

I am trying to solve a possible configuration bug in a web application. I would like to retrieve the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` value at runtime from Hibernate, is it possible? The JPA EntityManager is created successfully.

Thanks

Comment: i highly doubt,if that could be possible! Any changes to Environment level property would require rebuilding of SessionFactory, as it is immutable, but you can use the Environment class, re-instantiate the SessionFactory, and pass your own java.util.Properties version of hbm2ddl.auto to Configuration.buildSessionFactory().

Comment: Do you just want to read the property value?

Comment: @Narayan: it seems that OP just wants to know the property value, not change it.

Comment: @davidbuzatto Yes, only read it.

Answer (score 2):

After checking the source code , all the configuration parameters that are used to build `SessionFactory` will be stored inside its  [Settings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Settings.html) property .

Given an instance of  `EntityManager` , you can get the `SessionFactory` that is used to build it by the following codes:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
SessionFactoryImpl sessionImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl)session.getSessionFactory();
```

And get the `Settings` instance from the SessionFactoryImpl :

```
Settings setting = sessionImpl.getSettings();
```

However , according to following [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.5.Final/org/hibernate/cfg/SettingsFactory.java?av=f) of how to build this `Settings` instance from the configuration parameters  :

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
String autoSchemaExport = properties.getProperty( Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO );
    if ( "validate".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
        settings.setAutoValidateSchema( true );
    }
    if ( "update".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
        settings.setAutoUpdateSchema( true );
    }
    if ( "create".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
        settings.setAutoCreateSchema( true );
    }
    if ( "create-drop".equals( autoSchemaExport ) ) {
        settings.setAutoCreateSchema( true );
        settings.setAutoDropSchema( true );
    }
```

The actual value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` will not be stored in the `Settings` instance . It only resolve to different values of  `autoDropSchema` , `autoCreateSchema` and `autoValidateSchema` .You have to use these properties to determine the actual value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

Answer (score 1):

To read a configuration property you can try something like:

```
AnnotationConfiguration conf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
String confValue = conf.getProperty( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" );
```

Comment: From what I understand , it seems that the OP wants to get the value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` from an instance of EntityManager , but not from the configuration files.